# What does O stand for in V_CBO and V_CEO?

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I have just bought [this transistor](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC547.pdf). In the absolute maximum ratings, the voltage names end in `O`, such as `V_CBO`, `V_CEO` and `V_EBO`.

What does the `O` stand for?

Comment: It stands for "open".

Comment: Specifically, it is a measurement made between two terminals while the third terminal is open, or not connected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "O" in \$V_{CBO}\$ is short for "Open", not attached to anything.

\$V_{CBO}\$ will be the voltage at collector with base as reference (0V) with emitter not attached. For NPN transistors this is usually a positive number in tens of volts.

Same goes for \$V_{CEO}\$ where base is not connected.

I think you get the picture with \$V_{EBO}\$, though usually approximately 6V.

In case of a PNP transistor, same parameters are used but the values for it will be negative.